# Whoever deleted user "M-x" deleted my contribution to his *bad* question

Tags: support, specific-question

This guy (M-x) has been making a hoopla about how everyone should leave him alone to ask people to solve his problems without exerting any of his own effort.  And in the end I guess he decided to "take his ball and go home."  Good on him, as he is within his rights.

However, has all of his questions been deleted?  I improved an answer to this question a few hours ago:

[Creating a elisp function to convert URL to HTML link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706028/creating-a-elisp-function-to-convert-url-to-html-link)

And now the whole question is gone.  From some rough googling, it appears deleting a user should not delete his questions?

It would be a shame if all of our (people who answered his quesions) work were to be wasted because one guy wants to be a dick.

Comment: I guess that specific question was a special case, as it was so massively downvoted. I hope not all of his stuff was deleted...

Comment: I see the Meta question is gone as well. Shame, since it had some good info. A comment cleanup might have sufficed.

Comment: [So it has come to this.](http://xkcd.com/1022)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question had 2/3 undelete votes, so I cast my vote and it has now been undeleted. Case closed?

Answer (score 15):

Questions with a negative score are deleted when the user is deleted. This is the intended behaviour. Though I personally think open questions with upvoted answers should be exempt from this automatic deletion.

Comment: Where is this documented? Sounds right, but don't remember seeing it written before.

Comment: So the whole "please delete my question" debate had no point? Hahahaha.

Comment: @bart zero-effort user gone, quality answers restored. Sounds like the best possible outcome actually.

Comment: @BenBrocka In the end, yes.

Comment: So. It has come to this.

Comment: I'd support your last sentence as a feature request. Hadn't thought of the implications of user deletion and downvoted posts with good answers.

Answer (score 0):

M-x here.  I was browsing through the sencha-touch-2 tag trying to gather some of my old questions for reference and I noticed when my account was deleted that all the upvote reputation that I had given to people was removed.  I thought I had 42 questions in that forum, but I could only dig up 26 question.

[Referencing a Store in app.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090369/referencing-a-store-in-app-js)

[Sencha Touch 2 Standard Themes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106860/sencha-touch-2-standard-themes)

[How to make button grid resize to fit screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112124/how-to-make-button-grid-resize-to-fit-screen)

[Creating a 2x2 Button Grid with Centered Buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126628/creating-a-2x2-button-grid-with-centered-buttons)

[How to add a Search Bar to a Nested List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235735/how-to-add-a-search-bar-to-a-nested-list)

[Changing the Detail Container in a NestedList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252440/changing-the-detail-container-in-a-nestedlist)

[How to Add a Button to Each Row of a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286026/how-to-add-a-button-to-each-row-of-a-list)

[Adding a click event to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298683/adding-a-click-event-to-a-span)

[Adding buttons to a dataview row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320706/adding-buttons-to-a-dataview-row)

[Adding a searchfield keyup listener on object creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389715/adding-a-searchfield-keyup-listener-on-object-creation)

[Loading external URLs into tabpanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535721/loading-external-urls-into-tabpanels)

[Highlighting the selected row in a ComponentView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621294/highlighting-the-selected-row-in-a-componentview)

[How to add a custom update on a pull refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658400/how-to-add-a-custom-update-on-a-pull-refresh)

[Vbox layout issue in a tab panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757088/vbox-layout-issue-in-a-tab-panel)

[Grouped NestedLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809164/grouped-nestedlists)

[PNG images with hot spots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886362/png-images-with-hot-spots)

[How does one format a number with commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919575/how-does-one-format-a-number-with-commas)

[Centering segmented button in container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937936/centering-segmented-button-in-container)

[Getting store dump in Chrome/Firefox Javascript console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164500/getting-store-dump-in-chrome-firefox-javascript-console)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349843/dynamically-updating-container-values-from-a-store-with-combo-change

[Loading a Store with POST proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461723/loading-a-store-with-post-proxy)

[How to push Ext.Panel when row selected on Ext.List in Sencha Touch 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181831/how-to-push-ext-panel-when-row-selected-on-ext-list-in-sencha-touch-2-0)

[Drawing Html tables on a Panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401355/drawing-html-tables-on-a-panel)

[Flipboard UI in Sencha Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470218/flipboard-ui-in-sencha-touch)

[How to Embed a NestedList in a TabPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708945/how-to-embed-a-nestedlist-in-a-tabpanel)

When I had my account deleted, I had  about 62 questions with a 91% accept rate.  In addition, I frequently upvoted good answers to encourage people, especially in sencha-touch-2 because about 1/3 of questions there go unanswered.  Needless to say, some people lost hundreds of rep.  One guy lost close to 400.  I had one other question that got downvoted in a meta feeding frenzy that had a good answer.  From looking at one of my last questions, it doesn't look like bounty or checks are removed from rep:

[Orienting text on the back of a flipped card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602974/orienting-text-on-the-back-of-a-flipped-card)

Comment: Sorry sport, but when you turn in your marbles, you don't get to play anymore.  See Mad Scientist's answer here for an explanation for the missing posts.

Comment: Only two questions out of 62 had a negative score and one was restored.  My questions don't get negatives scores unless they have a run in with Meta.  I'm not losing anything here.  But some other people who worked hard did.  Help on the Sencha stuff is difficult to come by so I'm saving them for reference.  For everything else, I'm happy just to Google for it if I need it again.

Comment: You should be able to get a [mostly-complete list](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76274) from SEDE; I can pull the rest if you need 'em. Votes go with the account when it's deleted though.